# Surrounding each word from user selected text with a DOM element

Tags: javascript, textselection

From a DOM fragment coming from the user selected text [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection):

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>How <b>do y<i>o<i>u</b> do?</p>
```

I'd like to surround a `<span class="foo"></span>` around each word, ie:

```
<h1><span class="foo">Hello</span> <span class="foo">world!</span></h1>
<p><span class="foo">How</span> <b><span class="foo">do</span> <span class="foo">y<i>o<i>u</span></b> <span class="foo">do?</span></p>
```

How can I do this in javascript?

---

For now here is what I have:

```
// Get highlighted text
var selection = window.getSelection();

// Iterate over ranges
for (var i = 0, l = selection.rangeCount; i < l; ++i) {(function () {
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(i);

  var fragment = range.cloneContents();

  // HELP HERE: Surround each word in the fragment...

}())}
```

Comment: please post your javascript too

Comment: You can use .split(' ') http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514323/javascript-equivalent-to-php-explode

Comment: The answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171865/window-getselection-getrangeat-not-working-properly) question has a fragment of Javascript that may help.